# Parsing a string in R and comparing the values with another column

Tags: r, parsing

This may seem trivial but I am really stuck at this problem of comparing a value with this complex string

My data frame looks like this:

| Id | History | Report Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Jun:2020,030/XXX-May:2020,035/XXX-Apr:2020,040/XXX-Mar:2020,060/XXX | July 2021 |
| 1003 | Jun:2017,823/XXX-May:2017,000/XXX-Apr:2017,000/XXX-Mar:2017,000/XXX | July 2021 |
| 1005 | Apr:2019,000/XXX-Mar:2019,800/XXX-Feb:2019,000/XXX-Jan:2019,000/XXX | July 2021 |
| 1006 | Jun:2020,000/XXX-May:2020,030/XXX-Apr:2020,060/XXX-Mar:2020,090/XXX | July 2021 |

Key, value pair from the column history that will be used in comparison are as following:

```
Id : 1001 - Jun 2020,030   May 2020, 035   Apr 2020, 040...... 
Id : 1003 - Jun 2017,823   May 2017, 000   Apr 2017, 000......
```

Problem statement is: I want to compare these key, value pair with the report month (i.e. always current month) and make a conditional column based on it. Logic is: 24 months (could be 12 or 36) preceding July 2021 i.e July 2021-Jun 2019, how many key,value pairs have value >= 30 or >= 60 etc for months that lie within this time period. So if a string starts from <Jun 2019, like for 1003, the answer should be 0.

Output

| Id | Report Month | +30_last_24 | +30_last_36 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | July 2021 | 4 | 4 |
| 1003 | July 2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 1005 | July 2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 1006 | July 2021 | 3 | 3 |

I started with R very recently and have no solution to even begin with, so any help would be deeply appreciated.

*****MODIFIED ORIGINAL DATASET*****

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Id History ReportMonth
1001    Jun:2020,030/XXX|May:2020,035/XXX|Apr:2020,040/XXX|Mar:2020,060/XXX 'July 2021'
1003    Jun:2017,DDD/XXX|May:2017,030/XXX|Apr:2017,DDD/STD|Mar:2017,000/XXX 'July 2021'
1005    Apr:2019,000/XXX|Mar:2019,800/DDD|Feb:2019,000/XXX|Jan:2019,000/XXX 'July 2021'
1006    Jun:2020,000/XXX|May:2020,030/XXX|Apr:2020,060/XXX|Mar:2020,090/XXX 'July 2021'")
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data Rakshit?

Comment: How did you get 4 in the last column last row? Shouldn't that be 3??

Comment: @Onyambu yes it should be 3, my bad

Comment: @RakshitSinghal, see revised answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised Strategy in view of modifications-

- separate rows using `|` but only after escaping it with`\\`
- separate into cols using `,`
- extracts digits from values using `gsub`
- rest is pretty obvious.

Feel free to ask clarifications, if any.

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "Id History ReportMonth
1001    Jun:2020,030/XXX|May:2020,035/XXX|Apr:2020,040/XXX|Mar:2020,060/XXX 'July 2021'
1003    Jun:2017,DDD/XXX|May:2017,030/XXX|Apr:2017,DDD/STD|Mar:2017,000/XXX 'July 2021'
1005    Apr:2019,000/XXX|Mar:2019,800/DDD|Feb:2019,000/XXX|Jan:2019,000/XXX 'July 2021'
1006    Jun:2020,000/XXX|May:2020,030/XXX|Apr:2020,060/XXX|Mar:2020,090/XXX 'July 2021'")

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>%
  separate_rows(History, sep = '\\|') %>%
  separate(History, into = c('Hist_mon', 'Hist_val'), sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(Hist_mon = dmy(paste0('1:', Hist_mon)),
         Hist_val = as.numeric(gsub('(\\D*)', '', Hist_val)),
         ReportMonth = dmy(paste0('1 ', ReportMonth))) %>%
  group_by(Id, ReportMonth) %>%
  summarise(last_24_30 = sum(Hist_val >= 30 & Hist_mon >= ReportMonth %m-% months(24)),
            last_36_30 = sum(Hist_val >= 30 & Hist_mon >= ReportMonth %m-% months(36)), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      Id ReportMonth last_24_30 last_36_30
#>   <int> <date>           <int>      <int>
#> 1  1001 2021-07-01           4          4
#> 2  1003 2021-07-01           0          0
#> 3  1005 2021-07-01           0          1
#> 4  1006 2021-07-01           3          3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Anil thanks for the prompt response. I have few follow up questions, since I ran the code I found the string in column History has some varying formats:
1. Where you used sep = '/XXX-' , I need to use sep = '/XXX|' because in my data it is not '/XXX-' but it is /XXX|
2. Instead of numeric part before /XXX|.... it could be XXX/XXX| . for example :  Jun:2017,XXX/XXX|May:2017,030/XXX| or Jun:2017,DDD/XXX|May:2017,030/XXX|
3. There is no fix pattern after "/" this as well. I saw values with Jun:2017,DDD/DDD|May:2017,030/DDD
Apologise for not providing complete info in my original question

Comment: I have added a data frame in original question to have all possible formats

Comment: @RakshitSinghal, I missed your comments somehow here.  Just tell me one thing, how the digits in `DDD/..` will be considered?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  separate_rows(History, sep = '[|]')%>%
  filter(str_detect(History, "\\w"), str_detect(History, "\\d+/"))%>%
  separate(History, c("Date", "Value", "d"), sep = '[,/]', convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Date,ReportMonth), ~myd(paste(.x, "01")))) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(r = list(map(c(m24 = 24, m36 = 36), ~sum(
    Date + months(.x) > ReportMonth & Value >= 30)))) %>%
  unnest_wider(r) %>%
  right_join(df, 'Id')

  
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     Id   m24   m36 History_Report                                                      Month    
  <int> <int> <int> <chr>                                                               <chr>    
1  1001     4     4 Jun:2020,030/XXX-May:2020,035/XXX-Apr:2020,040/XXX-Mar:2020,060/XXX July 2021
2  1003     0     0 Jun:2017,823/XXX-May:2017,000/XXX-Apr:2017,000/XXX-Mar:2017,000/XXX July 2021
3  1005     0     1 Apr:2019,000/XXX-Mar:2019,800/XXX-Feb:2019,000/XXX-Jan:2019,000/XXX July 2021
4  1006     3     3 Jun:2020,000/XXX-May:2020,030/XXX-Apr:2020,060/XXX-Mar:2020,090/XXX July 2021
```

---

Comment: Hey @Onyambu - thanks for the prompt reply, could you please look at the question again, the string format has multiple variations inside them. I have provided dataset to cover all possible scenarios. Apologies for not providing the complete info with my original question

Comment: @RakshitSinghal some are characters instead of numbers eg `DDD/XXX` how would you like to treat them?

Comment: I would like to treat them as 0. It means the actual number was not reported, so I have no other option but to take them as 0. Basically if anything before the ‘/‘ is in a non numerical format like XXX or DDD.. then it should be just ignored or considered as 0

Comment: this solution seems to work but there is one problem with summarize. My data has duplicate Ids and I want the result for those in a non aggregated manner. Right now for 4 duplicated ids it is giving me same result, I guess because of the right join at the last. Is there a way I can do it without summarizing the result at the end and just have the result of individual rows in front of them. I tried mutate instead of summarize but it didn't work

Comment: @RakshitSinghal at the very beginning do `df %>% rownames_to_column()...` and in the groupby include `groupby(rowname)`

Comment: The records with only XXX in place of value are getting completely removed from the final output. For eg:
Oct:2010,XXX/XXX|Sep:2010,XXX/XXX|Aug:2010,XXX/XXX|Jul:2010,XXX/XXX|
Oct:2010,XXX/XXX|
Aug:2010,XXX/XXX|Jul:2010,XXX/XXX|Jun:2010,XXX/XXX|May:2010,XXX/XXX|

records like these with only XXX as value in place of integer value, I don't get them in output. Although they are all supposed to be 0, but I do need them in output.